# Orthogonal matrix simple identity?

Tags: matrices, tensors, trace

In order to prove the invariance of the trace of a tensor under the transformation
$\tilde{T}^{i,j}=\Sigma_{k,l} O^i_kO^j_lT^{k,l}$ where $O\in SO(3)$

I have to prove that
$\Sigma_{k,l} O^i_kO^i_l=\delta_{kl}$ but I cannot see how to prove this...
any good reference/help?

NOTE:
I know that by definition of orthogonal matrix
$\Sigma_{k,l} O^i_kO^l_i=\delta_{kl}$

but in what I have written above both the orthogonal matrices have the same line fixed by $i$ (pay attention to the position of indices)

Comment: $SO(3)$ is the orthogonal group and for two matrix in $SO(3)$ we have $AA^T=I$.

Comment: If the $O$ matrix is orthogonal, that property is true by definition.

Comment: Note that $\Sigma_{k,l}O^i_kO^l_i=\delta_{k,l}$ is true by definition but what I have written above involves the same line in both the transformation matrices

Comment: @Caso Tensor summations must always occur between a lower index and an upper index. I don't think you wrote that formula right. Where did you get it from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is confusing. Everything would look more natural if you worked with tensors of type $(1,1)$, that is, $T_i^{\,j}$.  As you formulate the question, one should first ask what is the trace of a $(2,0)$-tensor? In order to define it, you need a metric $g_{ij}$. Then you may want to prove
$$
\sum_{ij} T^{ij} g_{ij}=\sum_{ij} \tilde{T}^{ij} g_{ij}. 
$$
Rewriting this, you get
$$
\sum_{ij} T^{ij} g_{ij}=\sum_{ijkl} T^{kl} O_k^{\,\,i} O_l^{\,\,j} g_{ij}
$$
which reduces to 
$$
\sum_{ij} O_k^{\,\,i} \, g_{ij} \, O_l^{\,\, j}=g_{kl}.
$$
This is a reasonable *definition* of an orthogonal transformation. Of course, if $g_{ij}=g^{ij}=\delta_{ij}$ then everything reduces to the Euclidean case and the "matrix" $O$ being orthogonal. But then there is no reason to distinguish upper and lower indices.